# Linq, select List Item where column is the max value

Tags: c#, linq

I basically have a List that has a few columns in it.  All I want to do is select whichever List item has the highest int in a column called `Counted`.

```
List<PinUp> pinned= new List<PinUp>();

class PinUp
{
    internal string pn { get; set; }
    internal int pi{ get; set; }
    internal int Counted { get; set; }
    internal int pp{ get; set; }
}
```

So basically I just want `pinned[whichever int has highested Count]`

Hope this makes sense

The problem is i want to remove this [whichever int has highested Count] from the current list.  So I have to no which int it is in the array

Comment: Once you have got refernce to item on list, you can delete by reference, index is not needed.

Comment: Are any of those columns unique?

Comment: Is it possible that multiple `PinUp`s have the same `Counted`-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order it:

```
var pin = pinned.OrderByDescending(p => p.Counted).FirstOrDefault();
// if pin == null then no elements found - probably empty.
```

If you want to remove, you don't need an index:

```
pinned.Remove(pin);
```

Comment: And if multiple `PinUp`s have this `Counted`?

Answer (score 3):

One way, order by it:

```
PinUp highest = pinned
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Counted)
    .First();
```

This returns only one even if there are multiple with the highest `Counted`. So another way is to use  `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<PinUp> highestGroup = pinned
    .GroupBy(p => p.Counted)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .First();
```

If you instead just want to get the highest `Counted`(i doubt that), you just have to use `Enumerable.Max`:

```
int maxCounted = pinned.Max(p => p.Counted);
```

**Update**:

> The problem is i want to remove this [whichever int has highested Count] from the current list.

Then you can use `List(T).RemoveAll`:

```
int maxCounted = pinned.Max(p => p.Counted);
pinned.RemoveAll(p => p.Counted == maxCounted);
```

Comment: Tim - sort of I don't want the value of Counted, I want the item array number

Comment: @CarstenKönig I agree I could have made the question clearer but saying pinned[whichever int has highested Count] would suggest that I want the specific item from the array

Comment: @CarstenKönig no it was wrong, the OP wants to remove the item with the highest `Counted` value from the list. I have updated though.

Comment: @CarstenKönig it was said... "List item has the highest int in a column called "....

Comment: @CarstenKönig nope: "Returns the maximum value in a generic sequence." From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb347632(v=vs.90).aspx. List doesn't have own `Max`, it uses LINQ extension method.

Comment: @Mike: i have updated my answer, the easiest is to get the max-Counted first, then use `List.RemoveAll`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var excludingHighest = pinned.OrderByDescending(x => x.Counted)
                             .Skip(1);
```

If you need need to have a copy of the one being removed and still need to remove it you can do something like

```
var highestPinned = pinned.OrderByDescending(x => x.Counted).Take(1);
var excludingHighest = pinned.Except(highestPinned);
```

Comment: I don't understand why he can't simply  use `pinned.RemoveAll(p => p.Counted==maxCounted)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, I never said they couldn't. For me though, `RemoveAll` suggests that there could be more than one.

Comment: @James: yes, but if that's not the case it doesn't hurt. Otherwise it's the easiest way to remove all with the highest value. The `Skip(1)/Take(1)` fails if there is a second `PinUp` with this value, also the other approaches which try to find a single item or index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well the question was clearly interpreted as it being a single max value (given the OPs description), as much as `RemoveAll` would catch matching values there is no requirement for duplicates from the OP. So either works, it's up to the OP to decide which one works for them I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
PinUp pin = pinned.OrderByDescending(x => x.Counted).First();
```

Comment: You would need a single selector at the end here like `First`/`FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

it is a sorting problem.
Sort your list by `Counted` in descending order and pick the first item.
Linq has a way to do it:

```
var highest = pinned.OrderByDescending(p => p.Counted).FirstOrDefault();
```